# For loop only loop one time

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

i have this code, suppose loop 5 time but it only loop one time only. How to make sure it will loop 5 time?.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5;)
    {

      $sql6 = "SELECT * FROM at_agent_management WHERE piam_reg = '$checkedValuesarr[$i]'";

        $result6 = mysql_query($sql6); 

        while($row6 = mysql_fetch_array($result6)){

            $reg = $row6['piam_reg'];
            $date =  $row6['piam_date'];
            $agency =  $row6['agency_name'];
            $branch =  $row6['branch'];
            $category =  $row6['agent_category'];
            //$template_id =  $reg_count;

            $sql7 = "INSERT INTO at_agent_view_receipant(piam_reg, piam_date, agency_name, branch, agent_category, template_id) VALUES ('$reg', '$date', '$agency', '$branch', '$category', '$reg_count')";
            $result7 = mysql_query($sql7); 
        }


         $i++;
    }
```

Comment: Please stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use PDO / MySQLi instead.

Comment: also, you shouldn't manually modify `$i` inside the loop's body - the `for` loop takes care of it for you.

Comment: for ($i = 0; $i < 5;$i++)

Comment: @manowar_manowar .. i have tried that.. no luck

Comment: Your query run?Are you sure?

Comment: I think you can use 1 SQL to finish all tasks, `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`. Try to read the MySQL manual.

Comment: the only thing that might abort the loop is if there is an sql error. Are you seeing any errors and have you set error reporting to display errors?

Comment: @jeff i not sure about the error because it can insert first loop.

Comment: @airi how how got the primary keys set (which fields)

Comment: @jeff the primary key is id .. auto-increment..

Answer (score 0):

From logic you have written,
There is checkbox values array and you want to use that value in Query.
You can try with Foreach Loop as below,

```
<?
$checkedValuesarr=array("1","2","3","4","5");
foreach ($checkedValuesarr as $checkValue)
{
    $sql6 = "SELECT * FROM at_agent_management WHERE piam_reg = '".$checkValue."'";

        $result6 = mysql_query($sql6); 

        while($row6 = mysql_fetch_array($result6)){

            $reg = $row6['piam_reg'];
            $date =  $row6['piam_date'];
            $agency =  $row6['agency_name'];
            $branch =  $row6['branch'];
            $category =  $row6['agent_category'];
            //$template_id =  $reg_count;

            $sql7 = "INSERT INTO at_agent_view_receipant(piam_reg, piam_date, agency_name, branch, agent_category, template_id) VALUES ('$reg', '$date', '$agency', '$branch', '$category', '$reg_count')";
            $result7 = mysql_query($sql7); 
        }
}?>
```